# Фраза в title сайта

Tags: html

Подскажите пожалуйста, фраза после вертикальной черты - это уже `description`? или как понимать?

[image: title]

Answer (score 1):

Применение такого разделителя в некоторых случаях гораздо более эффективно, чем использование обычной запятой. Данный прием следует применять только в обоснованных случаях, а не массово на всем сайте.

При этом желательно не ставить больше двух разделителей, так как поисковые системы могут посчитать тайтл с большим количеством "|" за спам — простое перечисление ключевых слов.

Существует мнение, что "|" является одним из так называемых "стоп-символов", которые нежелательно использовать в title с точки зрения SEO-оптимизации. Впрочем, это не доказано.

Подробно: [Тут](http://seo-in.ru/marketing/67-effektivnyy-title.html)

Answer (score 1):

Tег tittle - определяет заголовок документа, то есть он отображается в меню вкладок браузера. Если нужно указать description к странице, то вот так:

```
<meta name="description" content="Содержимое мета-тега «description»">
```